# bootstrap not loading when installed via npm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating simple home page, which uses bootstrap styling. The bootstrap renders correctly when i use the direct link, but when using a reference via node_modules it doesn't work.
The bootstrap is not rendered.
**Note -** 
- I am using a node server to render my pages.

```html
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

- I have tried this on both firefox and chrome, same error exists.

Comment: Hello, your question is incomplete. See the section where you mentioned `direct link` and `using this` those are missing.

Comment: Can you confirm that your `node_modules` is in the same directory of your `index.html`?

Comment: My index.html is inside public folder. So folder structure is like app/node_modules/ and index.html is app/public/index.html.